# Searching by attribute in AD C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am currently able to search through AD by NT ID using:

```
PrinciplayContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
UserPrincipal byName = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, txtTest.Text.Trim());
```

From there I can find any and all extensions easy.

What I want to do is be able to pull using the employeeID attribute and get the sn, SAMAccountName, EmployeeID

I was wondering if there is a way to create a new UserPrincipal and searching that way. 
Example:
UserPrincipal.FindByEmplyeeID

I was thinking something like:

```
   public static new UserPrincipal FindByEmployeeID(PrincipalContext context, string identityValue)
   {

      //dont know what to do here... sorry noob on this
   }
```

For example:

When I use:

```
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext AD = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        UserPrincipal byEmployeeID = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(AD, "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectclass=user)(employeID=JR02251206))");
        MessageBox.Show(byEmployeeID.GetEmail());


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

I get an exception of:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I have tried using just the princial of just (employeeID=JR02251206) or (objectclass=user)(employeeID=JR02251206) and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry enTry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=Users,OU=Users and Groups,DC=BLAH,DC=com");
        DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(enTry);
        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(extensionAttribute13=" + txtTest.Text.Trim() + "))";
        SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();
        txtBlob.Text = result.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString() +"\n";
        txtBlob.Text += result.Properties["mail"][0].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PrinciplayContext AD= new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
UserPrincipal searchTemplate = new UserPrincipal(AD);
searchTemplate.EmployeeId = tempUserId;
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchTemplate);

UserPrincipal user = (UserPrincipal) ps.FindOne();
```

That should be close to whay you started with...

Kevin Orcutt